# Mongoose Schema hook and typescript: property does not exists

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to create a simple user `Schema` with `Mongoose` in `typescript`

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

interface IUser extends Document {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  email: string;
  activeMembership: () => boolean;
  membershipExpires: Date;
  registeredOn: Date;
  lastLogin: Date;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  activeMembership: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
  membershipExpires: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  registeredOn: { type: Date, required: true },
  lastLogin: { type: Date },
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false }
});

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

But typescript keeps complaining:

```
tsserver says Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document'.
```

on lines:

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
```

and:

```
      user.password = hash;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a generic assignment `<IUser>`:

```
userSchema.pre<IUser>("save", function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Hopefully that helps!